# Accesing computed value in created from axios get request in vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, lifecycle

I am trying to access the computed value in created for get request.I have this **classroomBackground**  declared in data as string.

```
data() {
    return {
      classroomBackground: '' as string,

}
}
```

In computed value i am doing some calculation and setting the **classroomBackground** value

```
  computed: {
   background: {
      get(): string {
        if (condition) {
          return 'value1';
        } if (condition) {
          return "value2";
        }
        return ' ';
      },
      set(value:string) {
        this.background = value;
        this.classroomBackground = value;
      },
    },
},
```

i tried to do this in computed get:

```
this.classroomBackground = 'somevalue1'; 
 return this.classroomBackground;
```

i am getting this error in eslint:

```
unexpected side effect in "background" computed property
```

In post method i am sending the data from computed value

methods: {

```
 async onSaveClickSave() {
    try {
        const settings = {
          classroomBackground: this.background,
        };

        await axios.post<{ api }>('api');

      } catch (e) {
        handleAxiosError(e);
      }

}
```

After saving value while i try to get the data the value is not appearing in my input box.

```
     async created() {
    try {
      const settingsResponse = await axios.get<{ api }>('api');
      const { settings } = settingsResponse.data;
      this.background = settings.classroomBackground;
      //this.classroomBackground = settings.classroomBackground;
    } catch (e) {
      handleAxiosError(e);
    }
  },
```

this is my template:

```
<div class="d-flex">
            <VTextField
              v-model="background"
            >
            </VTextField>
          </div>
```

This is the partial part of the sandbox link where you can get the idea of computed part.Later i had to add some condition according to the value of a dropdown: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-platform-dyrv7?file=/src/App.vue

While trying to restore the data in computed i am getting this error:
while iry to restore the data i am getting this error in computed `Error in v-on handler: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

i want to store the computed value in some data property and later restore and update it by emptying the whole string i retrieved from database

How can i access the computed value in created in get request.How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide full code of the component, obviously computed.background.get() is invalid: it uses unknown var `condition` and will be not computed

Maybe you wanted to do something like that:

```
    computed: {
       background: {
          get(): string {
            return this.classroomBackground
          },
          set(value:string) {
            this.classroomBackground = value;
          },
        },
    },
```

to save and restore state

```
    methods: {
        save() {
          window.localStorage.setItem("bg", this.classroomBackground);
        },
        restore() {
          this.classroomBackground = window.localStorage.getItem("bg")
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.resore()
    }
```

[CodeSand box for computed with get and set](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-brown-0twuy?file=/src/App.vue)

In your codebox example, there's another version of computed background

```
    computed: {
      background() {
        return `linear-gradient(${this.degree}deg, ${this.colors.join(", ")})`;
      }
    }
```

this computed is hard deconstruct to original parameters, you have to write parser to extract degree and colors, and your parser will break on "#cccccc" if it comes through the text input.

so it is better to think computed as read only value, or one way value: you can write only to degree and colors,

For saving and restoring such computed you need to save and restore all underlining values

```js
    save() {
      window.localStorage.setItem("bgColors", JSON.stringify(this.colors));
      window.localStorage.setItem("bgDegree", this.degree);
    },
    restore() {
      this.$set(
        this,
        "colors",
        JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("bgColors") || "[]")
      );
      this.degree = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("bgDegree"), 10) || 0;
    },
```

[CodeSandBox for complex computed](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-boyd-ys6ge?file=/src/App.vue:1399-1779)

if you want to store the whole computed background to db you can do this:

```
 save() {
      window.localStorage.setItem("bgFull", JSON.stringify(this.backgound));
    
    },
 restore() {
      this.storedBackgound  = window.localStorage.getItem("bgFull")
 
    },
```

but recovery is done to another variable, which you need to use ot make computed background later

```
computed: {
   background() {
      if(this.colors.length){
         return ...computed from colors...
      }
      if(this.storedBackgound){
         return this.storedBackgound
      }
      //default
   }
}
```

but it is just an example, you may handle default, restored value in some other way

Comment: This is the partial part of the sandbox link where you can get the idea of computed part.Later i had to add some condition according to the value of a dropdown: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-platform-dyrv7?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: i have also updated the description

Comment: Sorry, provided sandbox have too many differences from the question you asked.
I'm Click add button, which triggers addColor(), which triggers computed.background() recall, which triggers redraw of `Final gradient` input field. so one-way background computation work. 
if you change the value in `Final gradient`, v-model catch `input:update` event, try to update background (but it hasn't setter), fails, and nothing renders while you don't press the add button.
What is the question? how to save the background generated by this form, and how to restore it?

Comment: yes this is the question. i misquoted.Once i save the background how can i restore it

Comment: i think while iry to restore the data i am getting this error in computed
`Error in v-on handler: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: i updated answer, and provided two different sand boxes, save and restore state works there

Comment: I have given the upvote.Like the way you mentioned for complex computed is it possible to do the calculation in another  way by avoiding computed.I only want to save the final string and later restore it while getting the value

Comment: i want to store the computed value in some data property and later restore and update it by emptying the whole string i retrieved from database.

Comment: add example - how you may do this